# Getting the base element from a jQuery object

Tags: jquery

I'm struggling to find the right terminology here, but if you have jQuery object...

```
$('#MyObject')
```

...is it possible to extract the base element? Meaning, the equivalent of this:

```
document.getElementById('MyObject')
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Yes, use `.get(index)`.  According to the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/get/#get1):

> The `.get()` method grants access to the DOM nodes underlying each jQuery object.

Answer (score 96):

```
$('#MyObject').get(0);
```

I think that's what you want.  I think you can also reference it like a regular array with:

```
$('#MyObject')[0];
```

But I'm not sure if that will always work.  Stick with the first syntax.

Comment: when I console.log `$('#MyObject).get(0)` inside the html tags is `:before` and `:after` when using chrome. Any idea what these mean?

Answer (score 9):

A jQuery object is a set of elements. In your case, a set of one element. This differs from certain other libraries, which wrap single elements and provide alternate syntax for selectors that return multiple matches.

*[Aaron W](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47837/getting-the-base-element-from-a-jquery-object#47848) and [VolkerK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47837/getting-the-base-element-from-a-jquery-object#47844) already explained how to access the first (index 0) element in the set.*

Answer (score 5):

I tested Aaron's statements on all the browsers I have available on my box:

```
$('#MyObject').get(0);
```

vs

```
$('#MyObject')[0];
```

**As far as I can tell, it is only a matter of personal preference.**

Functionally, both these statements are equivalent for both existing and non-existing elements. I tested the following browsers: Chrome 27.0, FF 21.0, IE10, IE9, IE8, IE7, IE6.

In the speed tests that I ran, it was not always possible to tell which variation was faster; the outcome was not always consistent, even on the same browser. For the speed tests, I only tested existing elements. My test results are [here](http://jsperf.com/jquery-base-element).