# How i can do this in jQuery? any trick to pass selector instead of jQuery object in $

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In JavaScript if I append a child which has an ID to another place then it's removed from original location where they currently are.

In javascript I have an event where I can get selector by using this inside the function

```
$('.').event(function(){
    this
});
```

This is passed to another function and they work fine. Now I want to pass the clone instead of the object; and remember that this does not have ID.

The old code works by passing `this` to function as `DoSomething(this)`

if I make a clone using jQuery `clone` then I have the jQuery object. So how do I get a reference to `this` instead of the jQuery object when working with the clone?

```
var clone = $(this).clone() // this is jQuery object. 
//how do I get this out of clone?
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting the base element from a jQuery object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47837/getting-the-base-element-from-a-jquery-object)

Comment: `clone.get(0)` is what you're looking for

Comment: "how i can make clone and passing them instead of jQuery;" ? if u try var clone=$(this).clone(); var id=$this.id;doSomething(clone,id)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if I append a child which has an ID to another place then it's removed from original location where they currently are.

Yes, but the same is true of a child node that doesn't have an `id` attribute as well. An `id` is only an easy way for you to get a reference to the Element node object; it makes no difference to DOM insertion of cloning behaviour.

> In javascript I have an event where I can get selector by using `this` inside the function

No, `this` in an event handler gives you the DOM Element node object, not a selector string. A Node can be turned into a jQuery wrapper around it using `$(node)` and a selector can be turned into a jQuery wrapper on the list of matching nodes using `$(selector)` but other than this overloading in the jQuery API they're completely different animals.

To pull a Node back out of a jQuery wrapper you can use the [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) method or simple array-like access:

```
var clonedNode= $(this).clone()[0];

var clonedNode= $(this).clone().get(0);
```

to taste. (`get()` has some extra features which you don't need here.)

To get the selector used to create a jQuery wrapper you can use the [`selector`](http://api.jquery.com/selector/) property, but this won't return anything if the wrapper was created from a node object (`$(this)`) rather than a selector.

Answer (score 1):

`$(this).clone().get(0)`. This will get the first matching DOMElement from the jQUery object.

Answer (score 1):

To get the DOMElement object from a jQuery object use [get(0)](http://api.jquery.com/get/):

```
var clone = $(this).clone(); // this is jQuery object. 
var el = clone.get(0); // this is DOMElement object
```

Comment: I believe the recommended way to get the DOM element is through array index `[0]` instead of `.get(0)`.

Comment: @Tomalak I've never read anything to suggest one or the other, but if there is a recommendation it would be great to see it.

Comment: Hm, I vaguely remember such a recommendation in the jQuery API docs. Of course I can't find it now. I must be mistaken.