# HTML5 setting audio source in javascript not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Due to HTML5 browser formats tricks I have to put fallback audio formats also in audio format.  I want to set the src of source in audio programmatically but it is not working.

This is my HTML code:

```
<audio id="audioPlayer" width="400" height="30" controls="controls">        
    <source id="oggSource" type="audio/ogg" />
    <source id="mp3Source" type="audio/mp3" />
</audio>
```

Then in javascript using jquery I set the source for each of them (I have one audio tag and many mp3 on page and based on some event I want to change the source of audio tag) so I can't specify src directly in audio mainly because I need fallback support and also I need dynamism.

Using jquery I manipulate the src:

```
$('#oggSource').attr('src', 'OggFormat.ogg');
$('#mp3Source').attr('src','Mp3Format.mp3');
```

But this however doesn't work. Any idea why?

If I use:

```
<audio id="audioPlayer" width="400" height="30" controls="controls">        
    <source id="oggSource" type="audio/ogg" src="OggFormat.ogg" />
    <source id="mp3Source" type="audio/mp3" src="Mp3Format.mp3"/>
</audio>
```

it works but as I need I need to set it in code and not provide statically.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using `.detach().appendTo(parent)` seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/b7Jgh/.

```
$("#oggSource").attr("src", "foo.ogg").detach().appendTo("#audioPlayer");
```

I guess the browser only starts loading (and playing with `autoplay`) if a `<source>` element is *added*, not when it is just modified. I'm not sure why though, but appending it after detaching works.

---

**Edit:** You can also directly do `.appendTo` since an element is unique (i.e. it has to be detached anyway): http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/b7Jgh/6/.

```
function updateSource(source, src) {
    source = $(source);
    source.attr("src", src).appendTo(source.parent());
}
```

Comment: Great!! I wasted 1 hour behind this thinking I have done something wrong :)

Comment: Doesn't work on android browser but does work in chrome for android

Answer (score 2):

After you set the src attribute on the source element, call load() and then play() on the audio element. (Or, just load() if you have the autoplay attribute set.)

Comment: doesn't work atleast in Chrome. Calling load() didn't do anything and calling play() $('#audioPlayer').play() threw exception that no method named play exists.

Comment: @Anthony, you have to call these on the element itself, not the Jquery object. Maybe <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47837/getting-the-base-element-from-a-jquery-object> is what you need? I don't use Jquery, so don't know.

Comment: Hmmm.. Right..calling it on jquery doesn't work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `document.getElementById("oggSource").src = 'OggFormat.ogg'` etc.?