# How do I get a specific value from a jQuery object?

Tags: jquery

If I have an object like this:

```
var item = {
    id: '1',
    description: 'something'
}
```

then how do I extract one of these values? If I do

```
alert($(item.id));
```

then I just get an alert saying 'Object object'. I had a look at this post: [Getting the base element from a jQuery object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47837/getting-the-base-element-from-a-jquery-object) and tried to invoke

```
alert($(item).get(0));
```

But with the same result.

Also, from a terminology point of view what are objects like this called so that next time I can be a bit more specific?

Comment: Why not use just `alert(item.id);`?

Comment: What...? Why can't you just call it using its name and key..? `jQuery` is not a king of javascript, you shouldn't need thy king everytime..

Comment: What are you *really* trying to do?

Comment: unfortunately I'm one of those people who started learning about jQuery before javascript.

Comment: @NiftyDude, not everyone is a JavaScript expert or knows the difference between jQuery and JS. I think your comment could have been a little nicer

Comment: @markp3rry have a look at this nice guide: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/learn/javascript it will give you all the things you need to get started...

Comment: @andyb wow, perhaps you could be a little bit less judgmental.. :S, I was sincerely wondering why he can't just use, as like binarious' comment, and the rest of my sentence was just me fooling around.

Comment: Share the love guys. Thanks for everyones help and comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
console.log(item.id)
```

`$()` returns a jQuery object.

Answer (score 5):

Just use:

```
alert(item.id);
```

This: `$(item.id)` wraps item.id into a jQuery object, that's why you get 'Object object'

PS

What you're creating is an object in [object literal notation](http://www.fotiweb.com/2006/12/13/javascript-object-literal-notation/), that is a set of comma-separated name/value pairs inside curly braces.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

alert($item .prop('id'));

Answer (score 0):

Using normal procedure:

```
alert(item.id);
```

Using jQuery :

```
alert($(item).get(0).id);
```

**NOTE**

```
 $(item) -> return an array

 $(item).get(0) -> return object which is equal to (var item)

 $(item).get(0).id -> return id value
```