# What are the limitations on an unattached DOM element in JS or JQuery created dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The problem I had originates from trying to develop a custom control for Google Maps which has many examples using raw Javascript. I am trying to adapt the code to use JQuery to make it simple. This background is important to understand the WHY I am doing what I am doing.

I narrowed the problem to the following very simple-looking small segment of the code:

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
       ...
      var jq_outer_div = $('<div id="outer_div"></div>');
      // $('body').append(jq_outer_div);
      outer_div = $('#outer_div').get(0);
      outer_div.index = 1; // PROBLEM. Reports error shown below
      map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP].push(outer_div);
      $('#outer_div').append('<div id="control_div">Home</div>');
       ...
   });
```

I am trying to get simple JS element from JQuery objects (as posted on several questions in this forum) and then assigning an index to it. For example, see: [Getting the base element from a jQuery object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47837/getting-the-base-element-from-a-jquery-objectIt). It  gives me the following error at the PROBLEM line:

```
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'index' of undefined
```

When I attach the "jq_outer_div" element to the "body" element, it works. I commented that line to highlight the question. QUESTION: Can an element be created as a JQuery object, then extract the pure non-JQuery element from it and then add properties to this element all without attaching it anywhere in the DOM?

This works (element not attached anywhere, or is it?):

```
 var myElement = document.createElement('div');
 myElement.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
```

Then why am I getting an error above while specifying a value for the index attribute of an unattached element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you are getting is because you are trying to get an element that is not on your DOM.
if you just do:

```
   $(document).ready(function () {...
 var jq_outer_div = $('<div id="outer_div"></div>');
 // $('body').append(jq_outer_div);
 outer_div = jq_outer_div.get(0);
 outer_div.index = 1; // Reports error shown below
 map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP].push(outer_div);
 //$('#outer_div').append('<div id="control_div">Home</div>');
 //adding the div to the object:
 jq_outer_div.append('<div id="control_div">Home</div>');
 //adding the object to the DOM:
 $('body').append(jq_outer_div);...
```

});

You should not get an error.

Comment: I am accepting your answer and upvoting it but will you clarify the following? Which statement(s) in the code actually attach the element(s) to the DOM? I suspect it is the ....push(). Is it?  Thanks.

Comment: Though I expected your solution to work, it does not. Sorry to get back to you after a day or two. It works with the comments taken out for obvious reasons and I had persisted with that solution. However when a similar situation arose, I tried to work with your approach. It did not work. So I revisited your answer. The error I get is in the line: $('#outer_div').append('<div id="control_div">Home</div>'); The error is: Uncaught ReferenceError: control_div is not defined. Any thoughts?

Comment: Sorry, only saw your comments today, the push will only add the element to the array, it will no be added to the DOM. When you are doing the `$('#outer_div').append('<div id="control_div">Home</div>');` the outer_div does not exists in the DOM, you will need to add the new div to the object or append the element to another DOM element.

Comment: LAST QUESTION: Sorry for all these questions but I really want to nail this one down. What you mean by "you will need to add the new div to the object or append the element to another DOM element" means really that somehow the element has to be attached to the DOM for .push to do anything with it. .push() will not attach the element to the DOM if it is unattached. Right?

Comment: I changed the code in my answer to try and help on your previews comment. What i mean is that the push only adds the object to an ARRAY. You can have some code, after what you showed, that can add the elements in the array to your DOM, when you do the `$('#outer_div')` the outer_div element does not exist in your DOM, so `$('#outer_div')` doesn't return an element, that must be why you get an error.

Answer (score 0):

You just assign your div inside a variable but not put it insise the DOM so it does not exist yet, try to remove your comment of appending your `jq_outer_div` to the `body`

```
var jq_outer_div = $('<div id="outer_div"></div>');
$('body').append(jq_outer_div);
var outer_div = $('#outer_div').get(0);
```

Comment: I already know (as stated in the post) that removing the comment takes care of the problem. I wanted to know why and that was answered by Paraiso. Thanks anyway.