# the second parameter of packery fit method(jQuery)?

Tags: jquery, packery

I am using the packery library.

The problem is about the second parameter of `fit` method. The document says it should be an [element](http://packery.metafizzy.co/methods.html#fit), but I have no idea of what 'element' means.

The following link is an example of my problem.

[Link](http://jsfiddle.net/9Q5sZ/1/)

When I click the resize button, `fit` seems not working. If it's working, when I resize 'post 1', 'post 2' should go to the second row rather than being overlapping.

The following link is an example of what I mean, but I wish to trigger by buttons instead.

[Link](http://jsfiddle.net/9Q5sZ/2/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/9Q5sZ/3/ check this fiddle

```
if (isLarge) {
        $("div#container").packery('fit', div[0]);
    }
```

to provide the target Element use div[0].

The variable "div" is the Jquery output object ,which during runtime will be an Object Array

```
div: jQuery.fn.init[1]
0: div.post.large
context: button.resize
length: 1
prevObject: jQuery.fn.init[1]
__proto__: Object[0]
```

as you can see additional parameters like context,*proto*,length etc.But your Packery plugin required only exact div object (this object  is meant by element in the packery documents).hence div[0] will provide exact div object

```
div[0]: div.post
accessKey: ""
align: ""
attributes: NamedNodeMap
baseURI: "http://fiddle.jshell.net/9Q5sZ/3/show/"
childElementCount: 2
childNodes: NodeList[5]
children: HTMLCollection[2]
classList: DOMTokenList[1]
className: "post"
clientHeight: 100
clientLeft: 3
clientTop: 3
clientWidth: 211
contentEditable: "inherit"
dataset: DOMStringMap
dir: ""
draggable: false
firstChild: text
firstElementChild: button.resize
hidden: false
id: ""
innerHTML: "↵        <button class="resize">resize</button>↵        <div>post 1</div>↵    "
innerText: "resize↵post 1↵"
isContentEditable: false
lang: ""
lastChild: text
lastElementChild: div
localName: "div"
namespaceURI: "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
nextElementSibling: div.post
nextSibling: text
nodeName: "DIV"
nodeType: 1
nodeValue: null
offsetHeight: 106
offsetLeft: 0
offsetParent: div#container
offsetTop: 0
offsetWidth: 217
onabort: null
onbeforecopy: null
onbeforecut: null
onbeforepaste: null
onblur: null
oncancel: null
oncanplay: null
oncanplaythrough: null
onchange: null
onclick: null
onclose: null
oncontextmenu: null
oncopy: null
oncuechange: null
oncut: null
ondblclick: null
ondrag: null
ondragend: null
ondragenter: null
ondragleave: null
ondragover: null
ondragstart: null
ondrop: null
ondurationchange: null
onemptied: null
onended: null
onerror: null
onfocus: null
oninput: null
oninvalid: null

//Object continues
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. If you have time to explain why `[0]` works, I will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47837/getting-the-base-element-from-a-jquery-object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47837/getting-the-base-element-from-a-jquery-object)   [http://phrappe.com/javascript/convert-a-jquery-object-to-raw-dom-object/](http://phrappe.com/javascript/convert-a-jquery-object-to-raw-dom-object/)  these further explain about jquery object and DOM object..please take a look

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I've been fighting with this stupid script for literally days. This solution worked perfectly. I'm literally bouncing with excitement after figuring this out.